# FTP of file is not working as expected

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to fetch a zip file present in FTP server. To provide the path details , I am using a parameter file and calling for same in the shell script.

Below is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Source the Global environment files
ARC_SHELL=`dirname $0`
export ARC_SHELL

echo -e " Reading Host details from parameter file"
. $ARC_SHELL/parameters_remote.prm

echo -e " FTP to remote server to fetch the files"
ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASS
binary
prompt off
cd $FTP_SRC_PATH
lcd $SRC_PATH
mget abc_*.zip
bye
END_SCRIPT

if [ -f $SRC_PATH/abc_*.zip ]

then
 echo -e "File transferred from remote server through FTP"
 echo -e "Unzipping the file in local folder now :"

 unzip -o $SRC_PATH/abc_*.zip -d $SRC_PATH

 else
  echo -e " No zip file found at FTP location. Exiting.."
fi
```

Error I am facing is . It is able to download the file from FTP but it is fetching the zip file as directory and without `.zip` extension and not as a file . So I am not able to unzip it in local folder.